# Using Vaadin with Astro

Tags: vaadin, astrojs

I tried to use vaadin component in Astro powered app. Unfortunately I get this error;

```
  Named export 'dedupingMixin' not found. The requested module '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/mixin.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
  CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
  
  import pkg from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/mixin.js';
  const { dedupingMixin } = pkg;
```

Here is a link to stackblitz;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-veapdc?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro&on=stackblitz

but in general it is enough to setup new astro app (https://docs.astro.build/en/install/auto/) install vaadin component;
`npm i @vaadin/button`
and import it in index astro;
`import '@vaadin/button'`

You don't have to use it, import is enough. I tried to use it in svelte component as well, same errors. Any ideas??

Comment: How about trying to fix the obvious error first? I.e.,
"Named export 'dedupingMixin' not found."

Comment: How would You fix this obvious error?

Comment: No idea, sadly. My point is that the code and error hardly seem related to the subject. No offense.